# Is officecdn-microsoft-com.akamaized.net a scam link?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am trying to download Edge for Mac.

However, after I completed the downloader, I found it's from non-microsoft.com domain:

`https://officecdn-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/MacAutoupdate/MicrosoftEdge-84.0.522.40.pkg?platform=Mac&Consent=0&channel=Stable`

Is that a scam? Am I hacked by someone? Why Microsoft should use such a weird link rather than microsoft.com?

I have searched with Google, some people say it's legit, but I also found a site claiming this domain has only 6% trust score, which I think is quite low.

Is this website really a scam? Where should I download a genuine version of Edge for Mac?

[image]

`https://www.mamma.com/us/akamaized-net/safe-or-scam`

Comment: I think it is not scam domain. Microsoft has a huge network and there can as lot of different servers. And we have to ask microsoft for why they chosen a weird domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Akamai server, used by Microsoft and other companies servers for software
distribution and other purposes, so it is safe.

If in doubt (and what I recommend), you can download Edge directly
[from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge).
Click on the small down-arrow near the "DOWNLOAD" button and select "macOS",
then follow the prompts.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a scam. If you inspect the source code of the page, you will notice that there are more than 100 links from the same domain.

@As advised by Moab on the comments, one should not just believe because there are 100s of links. So I tried to find out about the domain. A [search](https://who.is/whois/akamaized.net) on the domain shows that it belongs to [Akamai](https://www.akamai.com/), a company that provides Content delivery solutions. It is listed on the [Nasdaq](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/akam) stock exchange.

I found this [link] from a Microsoft blog showing a business relationship between the 2 companies.

> Today we are excited to announce the general availability of Azure CDN from Akamai offering our customers an additional CDN provider to choose from.

I think this shows that Akamai provides CDN for Microsoft, and the link provided by on the question should be considered as legit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: " you will notice that there are more than 100 links from the same domain." Just because they have lots of links on their own domain does not prove it is trustworthy.

Comment: @Moab True. However, the links are all from this [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). Unless Microsoft site was hacked, then we have to believe they should be trusted

Comment: @Moab I did a similar search as an edit to my answer to find out that it was already posted on the other answer.;)